# How to provide theme choices in an Android application?

Tags: android, themes

I created an Android app with holo light theme. After releasing it, some users requested holo dark theme as another choice. Is there any open source application that provides choice for the theme? Or can someone explain this process?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.androidseeker.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-apply-new-theme-to-whole.html